# Dividing multiple numbers in a list

Tags: python, discord

Sorry if this has been asked before but I couldn't find it. For my discord bot, I'm making a calculator aspect and currently I made it so you can only divide 2 numbers but I want to make it unlimited. `e.g. [10, 5, 2] = 10 / 5 / 2`
Here is my code so hopefully someone can help transform it into unlimited numbers.

```
elif operation.clean_content == "/":
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "Please enter your sum.")
        usersum = await client.wait_for_message(author=message.author)
        ssum = usersum.clean_content.replace("/", " ")
        c = ssum.split(" ")
        if len(c) > 2:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, "Sorry, I can only divide 2 numbers.")
        else: 
            results = list(map(int, c))
            await client.send_message(message.channel, "Result = "+str(results[0] / results[1]))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) for this.

```
>>> import functools, operator
>>> functools.reduce(operator.truediv, [10, 5, 2]) 
1.0
```